# Does Hellfire Warlock give me another invocation on its second level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

It's my second time playing 3.5e and I plan to go for the relatively simple Warlock 11 > Binder 1 (for Naberius) > Hellfire Warlock 3 > Warlock all the way to 20th level.

My question here is, since the Hellfire Warlock gives a +1 level to an existing invocation class per level, do I still get to add another invocation on the second level of Hellfire Warlock?

Comment: Hi Tempest, and welcome to the site. Please check our [tour] if you haven't already to get an understanding of how our site works. I've removed your second question - please ask it separately, since it's unrelated and there's no particular need to ask it alongside this one. You can access your second question still through the [revision history](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/56233/revisions), which you can always get to by clicking the "edited X time ago" link at the bottom center of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes.

This is clearly stated in the ability description (emphasis mine):

> **Invoking:** At each level, **you gain new invocations known**, increased damage with eldritch blast, and an increase in invoker level as if you had also gained a level in the warlock class. You do not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained.